# Does the inverse of this matrix exist?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

For a given matrix `B el. 12x12` the inverse is defined that $I=BB^{-1}$

In my example it is also given that $I + B^3 = 2B^2 - 4B$.

Does the inverse of $B$ exist and is there a definit answer or just a general?

And can you do the following steps?

$$ \begin{align}I &= -B^3 + 2B^2 - 4B
\\I &= B\left(-B^2 + 2B - 4I\right) \end{align}$$
with $$ \begin{align} B^{-1} &=-B^2 + 2B - 4I  \\
I &= -B\left(B^2 - 2B + I + 3I\right) \\
I &= -B \left( (B - I)^2 + 3I  \right) \end{align} $$

and,
$$ \begin{align}B^{-1} &=-(B-I)^2 - 3I \end{align}$$

Comment: Launch a Satyagraha against the matrix

Comment: yoou missed a sign

Comment: You don't have to do anything more after you first write: $$B^{-1}=-B^2+2B-4I$$

Comment: but thats not really a proof is it? But regarding the other stuff i wrote, is that mathematically correct to do that? Can you pull a `B` out, if its only `B`s?

Comment: Yes, by (left) distributive property of the ring of matrices

Comment: $I = B(-B^2 + 2B - 4I)$ implies $B$ has an inverse (in particular a right inverse) and shows what it is

Comment: What does B el 12x12 mean?

Comment: Just to repeat what was said above: You lost a minus sign in the very last step. ( But to repeat my comment: You don't really need any steps after your first $B^{-1}=\dots.$)

Comment: @Gandhi "But that isn't a proof..." What isn't a proof? You have a matrix $C$ such that $BC=I.$ It isn't hard to prove likewise that $CB=I.$ So $C=B^{-1}.$

Comment: Matrix multiplication is distributive even if it is not commutative.  So, yes, it is acceptable to factor out a B from the left side (or the right side) of each term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer not addressed in the comments.

If $B$ has entries over say $\mathbb{R}$, then you'll notice that the minimal polynomial of $B$ divides $x^3 -2x^2 + 4x + 1$, which does not have $0$ as a root. Since the characteristic polynomial has the same roots as the minimal polynomial, $B$ admits nonzero eigenvalues. Thus $B$ is invertible.

Edit: A WolframAlpha computation shows that $x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x + 1$ should have one real root and two complex roots. If $B$ is a $12\times 12$ real matrix, then the matrix whose diagonal is the root of $x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x + 1$ is a solution to the problem.